# How to use AJAX in master page when content pages have ScriptManager?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-3.5

In my ASP.NET 3.5 project, most content pages have ScriptManager control but the Master Page does not have. I now want to use UpdatePanel in the master page but it is not permitting to put another ScriptManager.

I cannot change to ScriptManagerProxy in content pages as the change needs to be replicated to around fifty pages.

Is there any way to use UpdatePanel in Master Page by either sharing content page's ScriptManager or something else?

Comment: Why don't you just once place ScriptManager on Master Page rather then on Content Pages?

Comment: Ah. I am not allowed to change other pages.

Comment: I am not sure you will be able to pull this trick without changing content pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

three ways I can think.

First way is to use place the `ScriptManager` inside the ContentPlaceHolder, on the other pages that also have  `ScriptManager` this will be overwrite, in the one that you want to exist, just not use this ContentPlaceHolder, if this is possible.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderID" runat="server" >
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScrMang" runat="server" >
    </asp:ScriptManager>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Second way is to make a second master page, come from the first, and use this second master page with ScriptManager and all the rest, if this is possible.

And last, change all 50 pages, move the `ScriptManager` to master page, remove it from the rest. Some time we do that :)