# Multiple ScriptManager on Master and Content Pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

So basically, I have a master page and hundreds of content pages. Every content page contains `ToolKitScriptManager`. Right now, I want to add `ScriptManager` on the master page and when I try to execute, error shows `"Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page."`

I know that I have to comment/remove every `ToolKitScriptManager` line on each content page. But for some reason, I **can't** edit hundreds of content pages just to remove those `ToolkitScriptManager` code.

What I want to ask, is there any solution so I can disable `ToolkitScriptManager` (on content page) from master page's behind code programmatically so I don't have to edit my hundreds of content pages?

**EDIT:**

From this answer's question: [How to use AJAX in master page when content pages have ScriptManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569855/how-to-use-ajax-in-master-page-when-content-pages-have-scriptmanager?rq=1) , there are 3 ways he could give. The last way is impossible because I still have to edit the content pages. However, I don't get what he wrote about the first and second way. If I have to wrap Content Page's `ToolKitScriptManager` with this:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderID" runat="server" >>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

then the Master Page's `ScriptManager` will override the Content Page's `ToolKitScriptManager`. Correct me if I was wrong. And if I was right, the first/second way is also impossible because still have to edit the content pages, right?

Comment: u know, if all the script managers are written exactly the same,as in really exactly the same, just search & replace them with blank ""

Comment: @Banana how come a scriptManager code in asp can be replaced with blank???

Comment: well you wanted to comment it right? its like removing it from the page. so just replace it with blank, as in removing it. i assume whoever wrote the hundreds of pages didnt bother customizing the script managers, so the are all the same just search and replace all of them with blanks.

Comment: and i meant search&replace using visual studio, not programatically, that really is impossible.

Comment: @Banana I'm not allowed to change content pages, even a character. Any other solution?

Comment: unfortunately im not familiar with any way of doing what you need, maybe you can search for an alternative for your problem? i assume you want a script manager on the master page because you plan on using an ajax extension on the masterpage itself?

Comment: you can write your code natively in ajax instead of using asp.net ajax controls on the master page

Comment: @Banana I use update panel on master page, so I have to insert <ScriptManager>

Comment: yes thats my point, if you are unable to insert a script manager, an alternative would be to implement the update panel. its not difficult, simply create a webmethod in your master page code behind and submit ajax call to it when needed and update a div dynamically as needed.

Comment: @Banana any references? I have googled it and many of them said that UpdatePanel always need ScriptManager.

Comment: @Banana have you seen my edit?

Comment: yep, content placeholders will be replaced but it still means you have to edit the content pages. and no, an update panel cannot run without script manager. you misunderstood what i meant, an update panel and scriptmanager are simply a bunch of code that implements ajax for your convenience. you can however, instead of using update panel, create one yourself. you create a div and dynamically update its content (as would update panel do for you behind the scenes). you need to read about .ajax() calls to asp.net pages

Comment: @Banana how about check from master page if there's a scriptManager on content page then we gonna wrap the code with content placeholder? Is it possible? Maybe I can use master page's init/pre-init event and check before the ScriptManager is being initialized on content page?

Comment: i have posted an answer, i hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your master page, handle your script manager's on Init and remove the toolkit script managers from the content page each time your master page's script manager loads:

MasterPage ASPX:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" OnInit="ScriptManager1_Init"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

MasterPage Code Behind:

```
protected void ScriptManager1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (Control _ctrl in ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls)
        {

            if (_ctrl.GetType() == typeof(AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager))
            {
                ContentPlaceHolder1.Controls.Remove(_ctrl);
                break;
            };
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: finally, it works. I appreciate your time and effort to help me. Thank you! God bless helpful person like you.